# Python Regex Match WillCard as the end of a word

Tags: python, regex, cpu-word, wildcard

I'm trying to use regex to see if there's a word with a string that contains `'*'` and `'*'` can't be either the start of the word or in the middle of the word;

For example:

```
ip* -> match
ip*5p -> not match
*ip -> not match
this is ip* -> match
give me *ip not here -> not match
```

I tried the expression:

```
p = r'(?!\*).*\b\*'
```

But it failed in the case of "ip*5p", it thinks it as a match.

But if I add "end of word" which is '\b'

```
p = r'(?!\*).*\b\*\b'
```

It failed in all the cases as find nothing.

Also, I tried

```
p = r'(?!\*)\b.*\*'
```

But still not working properly.
Any hint?

Note: Strings must have exactly one `*` symbol.

Comment: How many `*` characters can the strings contain?  Is it always just one?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, it's a match

Comment: Are you trying to capture the entire string, or just the word ending in asterisk?

Comment: Then you picked the wrong answer, @JudyJiang. Neither of Avinash Raj's patterns will break the pattern if there is more than one asterisk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below regex which uses positive lookahead assertion.

```
r'.*\S*\*(?=\s|$).*'
```

OR

```
r'.*?\*(?=\s|$).*'
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kH8oV5/4)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """ip*
... ip*5p
... *ip
... this is ip*
... give me *ip not here"""
>>> for i in re.findall(r'.*\S*\*(?=\s|$).*', s):
...     print(i)
... 
ip*
this is ip*
```

`\*(?=\s|$)` POsitive lookahead asserts that the character following the symbol `*` must be a space character or end of the line anchor `$`.

Answer (score 0):

You said that:

1. You only want to match strings that have `*` at the end.
2. There must be only one occurrence of `*` in the strings.

This means that Regex is overkill.  All you need to do is count the number of `*` characters and then test if `*` is at the end of the string:

```
match = mystr.count('*') == 1 and mystr[-1] == '*'
# or
match = mystr.count('*') == 1 and mystr.endswith('*')
```

As you can see below, this works for all of your sample strings:

```
>>> mystr = 'ip*'
>>> mystr.count('*') == 1 and mystr[-1] == '*'
True
>>> mystr = 'ip*5p'
>>> mystr.count('*') == 1 and mystr[-1] == '*'
False
>>> mystr = '*ip'
>>> mystr.count('*') == 1 and mystr[-1] == '*'
False
>>> mystr = 'this is ip*'
>>> mystr.count('*') == 1 and mystr[-1] == '*'
True
>>> mystr = 'give me *ip not here'
>>> mystr.count('*') == 1 and mystr[-1] == '*'
False
>>>
```